# Select a Custom instance from a list by a specific condition

Tags: c#, linq, func

Let's say I have the following class.

```
class Wedding
{
    public DateTime When { get; set; }
    public string Where { get; set; }
}
```

And I have a list of this kind of elements.

```
List<Wedding> weddings = GetWeddings(...);
```

So from somewhere we got a list.

For this I would like to use a method that can easily tell me if a wedding at a certain datetime is in the list or not (bool). Like:

```
public bool WeddingInList(List<Weddings> list, DateTime dateTime)
{
    return list.Contains(...)
}
```

I'm not very familiar with Linq and Func...

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: How do your title and question match? What did your try and what exactly is your problem?

Comment: Why is the question title about WCF? Please edit it to match the actual question

Comment: Because stackoverflow saved my previous question that I didn't ask finally... and I absently left that in... sorry. It is fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DateTime check;

bool weddingExistsAtCheckDate = weddings.Any(wedding => wedding.When == check);
```

Clarification:

The [Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb337697%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method takes a `Func<T, bool>` for T being the class that is in the container.

Assuming you had a function

```
bool SomeFunc(Wedding wedding) { return wedding.When == check }
```

you could have passed that:

```
bool weddingExistsAtCheckDate = weddings.Any(SomeFunc);
```

However, then you'd have to get `check` in there somehow. Anyway, the function above can be shortened to :

```
bool weddingExistsAtCheckDate = weddings.Any((Wedding wedding) => { return wedding.When == check });
```

Which can again be shortened to:

```
bool weddingExistsAtCheckDate = weddings.Any(wedding => wedding.When == check);
```

because all the other syntax was something that the compiler already knew anyway... anything else and it would have complained.

The resulting short version is called a `lambda expression`.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works. And from where comes the 'wedding' variable exactly? Where is it declared?

Comment: @Mitulátbáti: it's a part of the lambda syntax: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx

Answer (score 1):

In addition to nvoigt answer, you said you want it in a method. You can use an extension method so you don't have to use a lambda expression every time:

Declare this class somewhere outside in the same namespace

```
public static class extension
{
    public static bool IsInWeddingList(this IEnumerable<Wedding> weds, DateTime check)
    {
       return weds.Any(wedding => wedding.When == check);
    }
}
```

and call it's method on your weddings list like this:

```
       List<Wedding> weddings = GetWeddings(...);
       DateTime check=DateTime.Now; //some date
       bool result=weddings.IsInWeddingList(check);
```